# Get the index of long pressed item in listpiker wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a ListPicker say listPicker1 with items populated in it using isolated storage, when i long press (Hold) any item in listPicker1, a context menu ll appear having options like "Delete", "Cancel" etc. Now when i click on 'Delete', i wanna delete that item from the lisPicker1 which i am unable to do as i dont get either the index or the actual data of long pressed item in DeleteEvent Handler(even i had tried using GestureListener_Hold, but in vain). Below is the code what i had tried. PLs do help me out if you can. Thanks in advance.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker SelectionChanged="listPicker1_SelectionChanged"   FontSize="24"  ItemCountThreshold="1" Name="listPicker1"  Margin="6,0,102,513" ListPickerMode="Full" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >           
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="sp" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                       <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding ContactName}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="35" />                  
                        <TextBlock  Name="number" Text="{Binding ContactNumber}" Foreground="Azure" FontSize="28"/>
                          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu >
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Cancel" />
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
     }

   private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SaveNumber data = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as SaveNumber; //nullRef exception here//
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the contact from list?", "Delete Contact", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {       
           XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("People.xml", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SaveNumber>));
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                    {                            
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, DeletePersonData(data));
                        this.listPicker1.ItemsSource = data2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private List<SaveNumber> DeletePersonData(SaveNumber ob)
    {   
        //data2.RemoveAt(listPicker1.SelectedIndex); //selected index is always set to 1//

        this.data2.Remove(ob);              
        return data2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the root of the item that was long-pressed, then from here you can obtain the index of this item within the container. Using [LinqToVisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/):

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  StackPanel rootItem = e.OriginalSource.Ancestors()
                                        .OfType<StackPanel>()
                                        .Where(i => i.Name == "sp");

  int index = listPicker1.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(rootItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ColinE. but i don get ancestors() for e.OriginalSource. I have even refered to LinqToVisualTree namespace. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

SaveNumber data = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as SaveNumber;

Answer (score -1):

create a handler for hold event and then get the item using its index

listPicker1.SelectedIndex;

Comment: SelectedIndex is not set on hold event. It will be -1